# "Account determined from" meaning in logs

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-logcat

In my application I'm implementing in-app purchase using Google In-app Billing Version 3 API. In logs from my app I see:

```
D/Finsky  (26024): [1204] InAppBillingUtils.pickAccount: com.example.myapp: Account determined from library ownership - [2FJ...ZIQ]
```

Another time when I test my app and switch Google account in my phone I see:

```
D/Finsky  (26024): [1204] InAppBillingUtils.pickAccount: com.example.myapp: Account determined from installer data - [2FJ...ZIQ]
```

I'm curious:

-What exactly does these logs mean?

-Why sometimes I see the first log, sometimes the second one?

-Is there a way to find out what this [2FJ...ZIQ] means or decode it?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?  I am wondering the same right now.

Comment: I have same problem in InApp billing, do you get solution ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Did anybody found the cause and solution ??

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for the `Account determined from installer data` log: *Make sure you use the correct base64 encoded license key*

Probably too late for you, but I recently had the same log in my console and was wondering, why an in app purchase worked in one app whereas it did not work in another - both using the same purchase code.

I am using build flavours to build two apps with a common code base and I just forgot to use the correct base64 encoded license key. In my case, I was just using one license key for two different apps in play store...

Answer (score -1):

**Apps that contain in-app purchases (IAPs) and/or paid apps to provide a physical address.**
After adding Address, It will take few minutes to Fix this issue autometically.

[image: inapp purchase notification]